# Organizing a small academic conference. What are the tax implications?

Tags: united-states, non-profit

I am organizing a small academic conference in about 10 months. About 100 scientists from all over the world will attend the conference. The conference will take place in the United States. Each scientist will pay a registration fee of about $200 USD, a total revenue of about $20,000.

I opened a "business" bank account yesterday that can accept credit card payments. The business bank account is associated with my SSN. My hope is that in July, when attendees are making payments, that they can use credit card, Venmo, or international wire transfer. I can then use checks, wire transfers, or maybe even a credit card, to pay expenses.

I have no interest in keeping any of this money; all of the money will go directly to pay conference expenses. For example, paying for the venue, paying for coffee breaks, paying for IT support. If there is a any money after the conference, that balance will be forwarded to the next host of the conference, in some other location, managed by some other person.

I am not interested in setting up a corporation or an LLC. I am not interested in getting a business license either. I think getting 501(c)3 will also be too much work.

What are the tax implications of my scheme? Will the IRS count this as income? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Does the conference have any legal entity for itself? Is it a new conference?

Comment: @littleadv It is not a new conference. Biannual for about 16 years. It has no legal entity (that I know of). It changes host country every time it is held. Although it was in the USA about ten years ago.

Comment: You'll probably want to ask around in your university if they have a tax person to help you. As an individual organizer, I suspect the last step (forwarding the remaining moneys to the next person) would be the most problematic tax-wise.

Comment: And there might be advantages if the school is willing to officially be the organizer if the conference rather than it being you who does so. They're probably already tax exempt.